# MySQL Indexer Tezos Blockchain

Tags: node, blockexplorer, indexer

Is it possible to create a MySQL Database out of the Tezos Blockchain?

All Indexer that i know of (Conseil, NL Indexer) are based on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own indexer to pull blocks from RPC, parse them, insert into MySQL. That's what all indexers do. TzStats uses BoltDB and the ones you mentioned use PGSQL.